# SwiftUI Running Async Code Within Synchronous Handler

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, async-await, game-center

I am creating a game where, after a user signs in, I want to send their playerID to my backend. Since this is in SwiftUI, I have the following (btw I know we're not supposed to be using `playerID` anymore but this is just a minimal reproducible example):

```
import SwiftUI
import GameKit

struct SampleView: View {
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.local
    
    func authenticateUser() async {
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = { vc, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                return
            }
            if localPlayer.isAuthenticated {
                let playerID = localPlayer.playerID
                GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = localPlayer.isAuthenticated
                // here is where I would like to make an async call
            }
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sample View")
        }
        .task {
            await authenticateUser()
        }
    }
}

struct SampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SampleView()
    }
}
```

In the comment indicating where I'd like to place an async call, I have tried something like
`await myBackendCall(playerID)`
but this throws the error

```
Invalid conversion from 'async' function of type '(UIViewController?, (any Error)?) async -> Void' to synchronous function type '(UIViewController?, (any Error)?) -> Void'
```

which makes sense given that the authenticateHandler function isn't an async function.

What is the best approach here? I'd like to wait until I have the value for PlayerID, and then call `await myBackendCall(playerID)`. Any advice here would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a completion handler `async` use a continuation, it returns `true` if the user is authenticated, otherwise `false`.

```
func authenticateUser() async -> Bool {
    return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = { vc, error in
            if let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                continuation.resume(returning: false)
            } else {
                continuation.resume(returning: localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

and in the `task` scope write

```
.task {
    let isAuthenticated = await authenticateUser()
    if isAuthenticated {
        let playerID = localPlayer.playerID
        GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = localPlayer.isAuthenticated
        // here is where I would like to make an async call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a callback closure (like [`authenticateHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gklocalplayer/1515399-authenticatehandler/)), it invariably means that the closure may possibly be called multiple times. The appropriate `async`-`await` pattern would be an [`AsyncSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncsequence/) (e.g., an [`AsyncStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream) or an [`AsyncThrowingStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncthrowingstream)).

So, you might wrap `authenticateHandler` in an asynchronous sequence, like so:

```swift
func viewControllers() -> AsyncThrowingStream<UIViewController, Error> {
    AsyncThrowingStream<UIViewController, Error> { continuation in
        GKLocalPlayer.local.authenticateHandler = { viewController, error in
            if let viewController {
                continuation.yield(viewController)
            } else {
                continuation.finish(throwing: error ?? GKError(.unknown))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could do things like:

```swift
.task {
    do {
        for try await _ in viewControllers() {
            GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated

            // do your subsequent `async` call here
        }
    } catch {
        GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = false
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

For more information, see WWDC 2021 video [Meet AsyncSequence](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058/). But the idea is that [`withCheckedContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedcontinuation(function:_:)) (or [`withThrowingCheckedContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedthrowingcontinuation(function:_:))) is designed for completion handler patterns, where it must be called once, and only once. If you use a checked continuation and the closure is called again, [it will be](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation) “logging correctness violations”, because “You must call a `resume` method exactly once on every execution path throughout the program.”

Instead, in cases where it may be called multiple times, consider handling it as an asynchronous sequence.